# AWS Local container: how to connect to mongo db instance when invoking a lambda function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

When I try to invoke my lambda function locally it won't connect to the local mongodb instance running on the same bridge network,

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  lambda:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - S3_BUCKET_NAME=${S3_BUCKET_NAME}
      - MONGO_DB_URI=${MONGO_DB_URI}
      - AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT=${AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT}
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    network_mode: bridge

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASS}
    network_mode: bridge
```

And I've defined my docker image as,

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16

RUN npm install -g yarn

COPY package.json yarn.lock ${LAMBDA_TASK_RUNTIME}
RUN yarn install

COPY *.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "index.handler" ]
```

And my `index.js` file,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectToDatabase = async (uri) => {
  console.log("Connecting to the database.")
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log("Database connected successfully.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error in database connection', err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};


exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  await connectToDatabase(process.env.MONGO_DB_URI);

  var response = {
    event: event,
    response: 'hello ' + event.name,
    status: 'SUCCEEDED',
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
  }
    context.succeed(response);
};
```

When I invoke the handle, `curl "http://127.0.0.1:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"name": "Foo"}'` it times out trying to connect to the mongodb.

I am running this on a mac m2 silicon, I can connect to the mongodb with compass.